# ng-click clear values in inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have one weird problem, I have never seen this problem. I try `scope` value into input on click on `<a>` everything works ok but, if I have filled other inputs and next click in `<a>` values in rest inputs are remove. Have you any advices why this is going on?

file.html

```
<input ng-disabled="product.disabled" type="text" ng-model="product.productData.oldPrice" name="oldPrice" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required>
<input ng-disabled="product.disabled" type="text" ng-model="product.productData.newPrice" name="newPrice" class="form-control" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required>
<input ng-disabled="product.disabled" type="text" name="level" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productData.level" required>
<div class="input-group-addon level-add">
  <a ng-click="product.easyLevel()" class="add-field add-field-easy">
    <i class="fa fa-battery-quarter"></i>
  </a>                           
</div>
```

controller.js

```
app.easyLevel = function(){     
    app.productData = {
        level: 'fa fa-3x fa-battery-quarter text-primary level-higher-easy'
    }
}
```

services

```
userFactory.createNewCourse = function(productData){
    return $http.post('/api/courses', productData)
}
```

Variables: `app = this`, `product` is controller as.
Problem: if two upper inputs are filled and I click `product.easyLevel()` to insert `'fa fa-3x fa-battery-quarter text-primary level-higher-easy'` in third input, above inputs are removing

Comment: Try  `app.productData.level ="fa fa-3x fa-battery-quarter text-primary level-higher-easy"` in `app.easyLevel` function

Comment: @Hadi is right. You are overwriting the whole object, when you should be setting only a value, level in this case

Comment: @Hadi I get error Cannot set property 'level' of undefined

Comment: You should declare `app.productData = {}` firstly .

Comment: @Hadi thanks, works good

Comment: I will post as a answer. can you accept it?

Comment: of course, add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.because you want to modify just `level` property in `productData` object. and also you should declare `productData` object firstly.

```
app.productData = {};


app.easyLevel = function(){     
   app.productData.level =fa fa-3x fa-battery-quarter text-primary level-higher-easy"
  }
}
```

It's better define `var vm = this;` instead `var app = this;`